# ANTLR: match tokens with whitespace

Tags: token, antlr3, lexer

I want to match an expression with white space as single token. Following are my lexer rules:

```
HOUR : (INTEGER) ('hour'|'hours') ;
MINUTE : (INTEGER) ('min'|'minute'|'minutes') ;
INTEGER : '0' 'x' (HEXDIGIT)+ | (DIGIT)+ ;
fragment DIGIT    : '0'..'9';
fragment HEXDIGIT : 'a'..'f' | 'A'..'F' | DIGIT;
WS : ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C' )+ {skip()};
```

If I use '**12hour**', I get **HOUR** token. But I use '**12 hour**', get INTEGER and 'hour'. What can I do to make lexer return whole '12 hour' as single HOUR token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I use '12hour', I get HOUR token. But I use '12 hour', get INTEGER and 'hour'.

Yes, that is expected behavior. That is because `WS` are only skipped from parser rules.

> What can I do to make lexer return whole '12 hour' as single HOUR token?

Either include space-chars in your `HOUR` rule:

```
// Don't use `WS` in this token, or `skip()` will be  
// invoked and this token will also be skipped!
HOUR : (INTEGER) SPACE* ('hour'|'hours') ;

WS : SPACE+ {skip();};

fragment SPACE : '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C';
```

Or, the IMO preferred way, create a parse rule for such a thing:

```
hour : INTEGER HOUR;

HOUR : 'hour' | 'hours' ;
INTEGER : '0' 'x' (HEXDIGIT)+ | (DIGIT)+;
```